# Gnuplot seems to fail in linear fit

Tags: gnuplot

I have a problem with gnuplot.In my data there is a very obvious linear relation in a specific range. So I want to do a linear fit in that range. But gnuplot throws something like an orthogonal (to as it should be) out.
I created the following fitting-file:

```
set fit errorvariables
f(x)=a*x+b
fit f(x) 'Data1f.txt' using 1:2:3:4 xyerrors via a,b
g(x)=c*x+d
fit g(x) 'Data2f.txt' using 1:2:3:4 xyerrors via c,d
set xlabel 'U_G  [V]'
set ylabel '{/Symbol=\326}(U_{Ph}-U_0)  [{/Symbol=\326}U]'
set xrange [0:0.9]
set yrange [0:4.5]
set grid
plot 'Data1.txt' using 1:2:3:4 w xyerrorbars title 'Measurement 1', f(x) title 'f(x)', 'Data2.txt' using 1:2:3:4 w xyerrorbars title 'Masurement 2', g(x) title 'g(x)'
```

And it results in the following plot:

[image]

I don't know why it is not fitting the obviously linear part of the Data ('Data1f' and 'Data2f' contain exact the same values like 'Data1' and 'Data2' just with some data-points left out. (i tried that when the range comands 'fit [number:number] f(x)......' showed the same result.).
Even LibreOffice Calc was able to give me a fitting curve that resulted in the expected one (but LibreOffice Calc can't handle errors - only the data-points itself).

Comment: Just use `fit f(x) 'Data1f.txt' using 1:2 via a,b`.

Comment: Well the problem is, that i have to fit it with the errors

Comment: Could you provide the data so that we can check? Are the values a,b,c,d initialized to some reasonable values?

Comment: Yes, i will upload the data. But I am highly under pressure, to finish the work. Got for now around plotting the data. Nevertheless i would like to know for the next time i have to rely on gnuplot what happened there. So could take me a bit time to upload the data-files.

Answer (score 0):

Because you specified the range **after** fitting, gnuplot fits the linear function to the full data set, which you said is non-linear. Therefore the result is obviously bad. If you change the order of your commands, `fit` will only use in-range data and you should get a reasonable fit:

```
set xrange [0:0.9]
set yrange [0:4.5]
fit f(x) 'Data1f.txt' using 1:2:3:4 xyerrors via a,b
fit g(x) 'Data2f.txt' using 1:2:3:4 xyerrors via c,d
```

Comment: Yes, but as i wrote, I experimented with some range commands. Including setting the x range once before the fit-command and setting twice after fitting for plotting. This doesn't change the result unfortunately. As i said, there are in "Data..f.txt" just the relevant linear data points! In "Data.. .txt" is the full dataset. So I'm not plotting, what i fitted, because the range commands didn't work.

Comment: I mean, of course I'm somehow plotting what I fitted, but I plot the full dataset, while I only fit the linear data points (therefore the different .txt-names

Comment: Without your actual data it will not be possible to help you any further…

Answer (score 0):

You initialize a,b,c, and d with some value nearby that you are expecting. Then try it, it will work. Initially, the value may be some random garbage number and I could fix the same problem by Initializing the constants with some expected nearby values